# Does CruiseControl.net have debug and release like transforms for config files

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, web.config-transform, microsoft-web-deploy

I want to use a cruisecontrol.net like web deploy to transform my base web config file using a debug or release adaptation to transform the config file.  I know cruisecontrol.net uses something called nAnt, but am not aware of how to take advantage of existing configuration file transformations like [this one](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations) inside of cruisecontrol.net.  Is there a way to take advantage of these transformations?

Also is there a way to utilize web deploy within cruise control or is that breaking the rules somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Cruise Control does not know how to do this, however **msbuild** can with the inclusion of the web application targets file (`Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll`); these come with visual studio - maybe WebDeploy too - and achieve the same result as WebDeploy.

You could then write a simple msbuild project (.proj), or a task in your .csproj/.vbproj to invoke the transform.

E.g. (from http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/09/14/using-custom-webconfig-transformations-in-msbuild )

```
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"/>
 <Target Name="TransformWebConfig">
 <TransformXml Source="C:\Code\MyProject\Web.config" Transform="C:\Code\MyProject\TransformFile.config" Destination="C:\Code\MyProject\Web.config" StackTrace="true" />
</Target>
```